# Our XServe FTP area is not allowing external access

Tags: ftp, connection, xserve, external-connection

We are a graphic design agency and therefore we work pretty much solely on MacOSX. We have an XServe server and up until yesterday was fine. We have an FTP area where we can upload files to our clients and where the printers can download files from.

Everyone in the studio (who is connected up to the server) can access the FTP Area. Our project manager works on a Windows 7 Laptop and accesses the FTP area externally (in a similar way to our clients and printers). We all have an internet connection.

Our FTP area and the server itself suddenly cannot accept connections NOT on the LAN, so our project manager is out, and our clients accessing the FTP are out also. We've tried configuring it to different settings but cant seem to figure it out.

Can anyone offer a possible solution?

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the firewall, router, and server?

Answer (score 0):

What is the network layout? (ie. is there a firewall device? are you behind a nat?)

Also check what the rules are for the ftp access on the OS X server, you may have allowed access from LAN but not from outside of it.

You can print out the active rules with:

```
ipfw list
```

on a terminal window

Once you have that figured out you'll know where the block is.

You can also run a tcptraceroute on port 21 (ftp) from outside and see where it dies.

Comment: how do I run a tcptraceroute?

Comment: I haven't tried it on windows. On linux it's a fairly standard command. On Mac (which is what you're using) you'll have to get it through darwinports (http://tcptraceroute.darwinports.com/)
It's a terminal program, the command would be
    tcptraceroute yourhost.com 21

Again, if the FTP server is on a NATed network, you will have to specify routes from outside your lan towards your ftp server. 
It doesn't seem to be a Mac problem more than it is a network problem. Since anyone on LAN can access it, it's a matter of getting to it from the outside.